# how to insert a class including ComPtr value to a <map> container in C++?

Tags: winapi, directx-11, direct2d, wic, wrl

this is the class that I want to insert.
it has constructor initializes 'm_bitmap'.
In fact, Initializing m_bitmap doesn't cause problem.
I inserted for detail.

```
#pragma once
#include "D2DApp.h"

class Image
{
public:
    ComPtr<ID2D1Bitmap> m_bitmap;
    Image(LPCWSTR filePath);
};
```

and it's Constructor

```
Image::Image(LPCWSTR filePath)
{
    //Create Decoder
    ComPtr<IWICBitmapDecoder> bitmapDecoder;
    ThrowIfFailed(
        D2DApp::GetApp()->
        GetWicFactory()->CreateDecoderFromFilename(
            filePath,
            NULL,
            GENERIC_READ,
            WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnLoad,
            bitmapDecoder.GetAddressOf()
        )
    );

    //Get the current frame
    ComPtr<IWICBitmapFrameDecode> frame;
    ThrowIfFailed(
        bitmapDecoder->GetFrame(0, frame.GetAddressOf())
    );

    //Create the format converter
    ComPtr<IWICFormatConverter> wicImage;
    ThrowIfFailed(
        D2DApp::GetApp()->GetWicFactory()->CreateFormatConverter(
            wicImage.GetAddressOf()
        )
    );

    //Initialize wic Image
    ThrowIfFailed(
        wicImage->Initialize(
            frame.Get(),
            GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppPBGRA,
            WICBitmapDitherTypeNone,
            nullptr,
            0,
            WICBitmapPaletteTypeCustom
        )
    );

    //Initialize D2d image
    ThrowIfFailed(
        D2DApp::GetApp()->GetD2DContext()->
        CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap(
            wicImage.Get(),
            m_bitmap.ReleaseAndGetAddressOf()
        )
    );
}
```

then I insert it to the map container

```
#include "Image.h"
#include <map>

class ImageSystem
{
private:
    map<string, Image*> ImageData;
public:
    void addData(string key, LPCWSTR filePath);
    ComPtr<ID2D1Bitmap> GetData(string key);
    ~ImageSystem();
};
```

problem happens here, both two lines of code didn't worked for same reason.

Exception thrown: read access violation.
_Scary was nullptr.

```
void ImageSystem::addData(string key, LPCWSTR filePath)
{
    //ImageData.insert(make_pair(key, new Image(filePath)));
    ImageData[key] = new Image(filePath);
}
```

Comment: What's "_Scary" ?

Comment: this is the value inside the map header file. but I dunno what it is clearly.

Comment: Mixing `std::map` with raw pointers (to smart pointer objects!) is a sure recipe for disaster.

Comment: but how could it possible?